# Question about relationship of a function and its derivative

Tags: calculus

If a function has vanishing second derivative everywhere in the domain $\mathbb{R}$, then the function can only be a polynomial of degree at most 1, is that right? Can any function other than polynomials have vanishing second derivative?

Comment: Is the domain all of the real numbers? If so, your answer is correct. How do you show it? (If not, it's definitely not correct.)

Comment: @TedShifrin, yes, the domain is all of real number, but I'm not sure how  to show it.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\sin x$, then $f''(0)=0$. If it's not what you were looking for, maybe you should be more specific with "vanishing second derivative". For specific, I mean that specify the interval (or points) in which the second derivative is zero.

And yes, if you have a function $f$ that satisfy the *differential equation* 
$$f''(x)=0 \textrm{ for all } x \in \mathbb R$$
then this function it will be in the form $f(x)=a_0+a_1x$ for some real numbers $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f''(x)=0$ fro all $x \in \mathbb R$ then integration gives $f'(x)=c$ where $c$ is a constant and and another integration gives $f(x)=cx+d$ where $d$ is another constant. So it is necessary that $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree at most $1$.

Comment: Instead of "integration" you may use the simpler fact: if two functions on $\mathbb R$ have the same derivative everywhere, then they differ by a constant.